# Factory referring to association in after create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot, minitest

I have a factory for an account that has a relationship with a product. When adding an after create callback it is referring to the product and not the account.

#### account factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    billing_method { 'monthly' }
    workflow_state { 'active' }
  end

  after :create, &:create_api_credential
end
```

#### product factory

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    ...
    account
  end
end
```

#### test

```
subject { create(:product) }
it 'has an account' do
  subject
  assert_not_nil(subject.account)
end
```

#### the error

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `create_api_credential' for #<Product:0x00007fab7cefe2f8>
```

create_api_credential exist on account not product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to move:
`after :create, &:create_api_credential` to `:account` block?

```
factory :account do
  billing_method { 'monthly' }
  workflow_state { 'active' }

  after :create, &:create_api_credential
end
```